# DPDK: Looking for a vhost-user (zero copy) example

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

I am looking for a DPDK vhost-user example application, specifically the later version with supposedly offers zero-copy and without need for CUSE or eventfd.

The only vhost related example application I can find in DPDK is Vhost Sample Application (http://dpdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sample_app_ug/vhost.html) which by its description is based on the older vhost-net technique.

Comment: The best resource that got me started with 'practical' dpdk for OVS/KVM is http://people.redhat.com/~pmatilai/dpdk-guide/ . dpdk.org docs are all over the place and it's hard to distinguish what's the latest that is working

Comment: Alec, that seems like a good, detailed read! I will definately bookmark that one. Thanks!